# Bounding rectangle collision test?

Tags: c++, c

I have complex polygons which I know the minimum x, minimum y, maximum x and maximum y. I also have another rectangle which I know the top left and bottom right vertices. Knowing this information, how can I know if these 2 bounding boxes are colliding? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
typedef struct rect {
    int top;     // maximum y-coord
    int bottom;  // minimum y-coord
    int left;    // minimum x-coord
    int right;   // maximum x-coord
} rectangle;

// Returns 1 if the point (x, y) lies within the rectangle, 0 otherwise
int is_point_in_rectangle(rectangle r, int x, int y) {
    if ((r.left   <= x && r.right >= x) &&
        (r.bottom <= y && r.top   >= y))
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

// Returns 1 if the rectangles overlap, 0 otherwise
int do_rectangles_intersect(rectangle a, rectangle b) {
    if ( is_point_in_rectangle(a, b.left , b.top   ) ||
         is_point_in_rectangle(a, b.right, b.top   ) ||
         is_point_in_rectangle(a, b.left , b.bottom) ||
         is_point_in_rectangle(a, b.right, b.bottom))
        return 1;
    if ( is_point_in_rectangle(b, a.left , a.top   ) ||
         is_point_in_rectangle(b, a.right, a.top   ) ||
         is_point_in_rectangle(b, a.left , a.bottom) ||
         is_point_in_rectangle(b, a.right, a.bottom))
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

You can do the same for any polygon, just iterate through all of its points and call `is_point_in_rectangle` with them.  Since you only have a bounding box for the complex polygon, there is a chance that this method gives you a false positive (that is, the rectangle is inside the complex polygon's bounding box but outside of the polygon itself).  However, this restriction applies to any method where a complex shape is simplified to a bounding box.

Comment: I suspect this algorithm works much harder than necessary.  At a minimum, the second set of tests in do_rectangles_intersect() is redundant.

Comment: How could I do it more correctly to avoid false positives? Thanks

Comment: @Brian- The second test is necessary to detect the case where rectangle A is completely inside of rectangle B.  The rectangles overlap, but none of the corners of B are inside A.  You have to check the other way around for that.  @Jex- If you are using a bounding rectangle on the complex polygon, you can't avoid false positives.  If you are wanting to detect collisions between a rectangle and an arbitrary polygon, then that is a different question entirely.

Comment: Well can you answer it without me making another question entirely :p? thanks

Comment: You're right.  However, I think this is overkill for two rectangles: it's only necessary to check the bounds, not every vertex.  @Jex Polygon clipping gets complicated very quickly.  Check out http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~toby/alan/software/gpc.html.

Answer (score 2):

Rectangles A and B are colliding if the intervals [Ax1, Ax2] and [Bx1, Bx2] are overlapping *and* the intervals [Ay1, Ay2] and [By1, By2] are overlapping.

Comment: The OP mentions a complex polygon, so I think this test is too restrictive, albeit fast.

Comment: @yasp: It might be useful to eliminate polygons which cannot be touching, hence pruning the number of pairs needed to be checked using more expensive methods.

Comment: @ysap- The OP has *the rectangular bounding box* of a complex polygon.  This method works for any two rectangles, so it should be a valid solution here.  If the OP was working with the original polygon and not just a bounding box then yes, I would agree with your reservations about this method.

Comment: To test whether intervals overlap, the condition would be something like (min2 <= max1) && (max2 >= min1).  There are edge cases where the ranges touch but don't strictly overlap that you might consider.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following works **most** of the times, but it is surely more accurate than bounding box check, although more complex. Take a look at the following question:

[Polygon in rectangle algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453460/polygon-in-rectangle-algorithm/3453731#3453731)

There, you see an algorithm for finding out if a point is inside a polygon. You can apply this test to each point of the 1st poly w.r.t. the 2nd one. Then the opposite. If the test passes at least once, you have a collision.

Answer (score 0):

Create a sorted array of the x coordinates of the left and right edges of the rectangles. Then, use a "scanline" to move from left to right through the rectangles. Keep a binary search tree containing the y coordinates of the top and bottom edges of the rectangles that overlap the scanline. For each element of the array, check whether it is a left or right edge. If it is a right edge, remove the corresponding top and bottom edges from the BST. If it is a left edge, search the BST for rectangles that overlap the current rectangle; if there is one, return the overlap. Then, add the y coordinates of the top and bottom edges of the rectangle to the BST. The search takes O(n log n) time, since it takes O(n log n) time to sort the rectangles and each of the 2n iterations takes O(log n) time - Copied from google search results.

Comment: That sounds like overkill for determining if two rectangles overlap.  It might be a good solution for an arbitrary number of rectangles, but this particular problem is only using two.

Comment: ya true, its applicable for arbitrary number of rectangles. Thought it might be helpful.